# What connector do I need?

Tags: power-supply, power, connector, identification

Does anyone know what connector should I use on the picture below? All I know is it's a power supply connector.

[image]

Comment: Power supply for what? What is the supply rated for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your picture appears to *show* an "XT60" connector, commonly used (or abused?) on medium sized RC vehicles and some smaller electric powered personal transportation devices.

As for what connector you *"need"* that is a far more complicated question, and I firmly decline to make a recommendation here.